# Atan2 and Prolog

Tags: prolog

Why does `atan2(1,3).` yield `false`?

I expected it to return an angle in radians as stated here: http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/arith.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because what you have there is a fact database query, when what you want is mathematical evaluation. Compare this:

```
?- atan2(1,3).
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: atan2/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

To this:

```
?- X is atan2(1,3).
X = 0.3217505543966422.
```

The latter form, using `is/2` is needed to trigger mathematical evaluation.

On a more general note, outside a mathematical context, Prolog functions do not "return", they unify parameters, so a statement such as `atan2(1,3)` with no variables should only net you `true`, `false`, an infinite loop or another error.